# very low variance explained after applying pca

Tags: machine-learning, variance, pca

I applied PCA on MNIST data and found that the first 64 components are able to retain 86% of variance.

Is there any problem while applying pca to a big dataset like MNIST. Because in most of the papers I have read to take the components which can explain upto 99% of variance. But it would be pointless to apply pca if such variance comes at 120 pca components.

Comment: Why would a reduction to a dimension of 120 be pointless? If I recall correctly, the dimension of MNIST signals is 784.

Comment: its pca component not the dimension of mnist dataset